# Ruby gem for running clock tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm looking to use the clockwork gem for a clock process on heroku. Surprisingly there is no link to a ruby library from the heroku [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes) but after some googling it seems like clockwork is the [standard](http://gears.generalassemb.ly/2015/03/31/clockwork-on-heroku/) ruby gem. the url I've found on the web has been https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork but that page is throwing a 404.

I also tried searching github for Clockwork and found this [repo](https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork) but this still points to the tommykaira repo mentioned above.

Has this gem moved or been renamed?

Is this another ruby gem that is recommended for rails app to run a clock process?

Comment: https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork

Comment: @Rocco not helpful. this repo is linked above and is no longer maintained in favor of tomy kaira's branch

Comment: Fair enough. There does look to be a lot of them though including one in the [GA article you posted](https://github.com/endofunky/sidetiq)

Comment: @Rocco yeh but that one appears to be sidekiq specific

Comment: alright well this one looks very up to date and has a ton of documentation https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler

Comment: I recently did a similar exploration and was surprised to find there doesn't seem to be a standard solution. I remember years ago heroku did link to one (probably wiggins' since he founded heroku), but now removed it. I was inspired to make my own which you might be interested in trying: https://github.com/jjb/ruby-clock - it uses rufus for its scheduling logic